# Error in webpack when running npm run dev and dont know why or how to resolve

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, angular, webpack

I keep getting an error when I try to npm run dev in the command line. I did delete a package that I thought was not being used and forced a fix with npm audi fix --force.
I also tried to remove the node-modules folder and npm install packages again, but that didnt resolve the issue...

I now dont know how to resolve this issue, since I dont know what it means or why its happening.

here is the error output from the terminal:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01> npm run dev

> workshop_01@1.0.0 dev C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01
> npm-run-all -p devFast buildWatch


> workshop_01@1.0.0 devFast C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01
> webpack-dev-server


> workshop_01@1.0.0 buildWatch C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01
> webpack --watch


webpack is watching the files…

(node:11464) [DEP_WEBPACK_WATCH_WITHOUT_CALLBACK] DeprecationWarning: A 'callback' argument need to be provided to the 'webpack(options, callback)' function when the 'watch' option is set. There is no way to handle the 'watch' option without a callback.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from http://localhost:3000/
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01
assets by status 1.79 KiB [cached] 1 asset
runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules       
cacheable modules 186 bytes
  ./js/scripts.js 147 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./js/css/style.css 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./js/css/style.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap?, implementation? }
    at validate (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:104:11)
    at Object.getOptions (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:529:19)
    at Object.loader (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:42:24)
    at processResult (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:703:19)
    at C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:809:5
    at C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
 @ ./js/scripts.js 1:0-25

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack 5.38.1 compiled with 2 errors in 1480 ms
× ｢wdm｣: asset bundled.js 403 KiB [emitted] (name: scripts) 1 related asset
runtime modules 25.9 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 345 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ 21.2 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 20.9 KiB 10 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ 296 bytes 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/ 4.46 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 61 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/url/ 37.4 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/querystring/*.js 4.51 KiB 3 modules
modules by path ./js/ 2.21 KiB
  ./js/scripts.js 147 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./js/css/style.css 2.03 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?url=false!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[2]!./js/css/style.css 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]     

ERROR in ./js/css/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?url=false!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[2]!./js/css/style.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap?, implementation? }
    at validate (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:104:11)
    at Object.getOptions (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:529:19)
    at Object.loader (C:\wamp64\www\workshop_01\wp-content\themes\workshop_01\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:42:24)
 @ ./js/css/style.css 2:26-176 53:4-74:5 56:18-168
 @ ./js/scripts.js 1:0-25

webpack 5.38.1 compiled with 1 error in 5059 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

How can I fix my this so webpack can continue watching my project for changes I make?

Please help :/

Comment: Looks like you have a config error in PostCSS

Comment: As you can see, I amended my response.

Comment: PostCSS, okay. Should I uninstall and reinstall it again?

Comment: From your error log: ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

Comment: I would look at the API schema and make sure you're passing the config object correctly.

Comment: Where is the API schema and what should I be passing in the config object? I am totally green at this

Comment: https://github.com/postcss/postcss  It seems the error is originating from `./js/css/style.css`

Comment: I have no idea how to resolve this. Would you suggest I remove the package-lock.json and the node-modules folder and type npm install to reinstall them again?

Comment: Well, that didnt work :/

Comment: Try following the steps mentioned in this docs . This should help as you are missing something related to configuration.
https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/

Comment: FYI, you wrote 'npm audi fix' and not `npm audit fix'